# Unable to display user data on the textbox

Tags: javascript, html

A parking garage charges a $2.00 minimum fee to park for up to three hours. It charges an additional $0.50 per hour for each hour or part thereof in excess of three hours. The maximum charge for any given 24-hour period is $10.00. Assume that no car parks for longer than 24 hours at a time.

The web page should calculate the entry hour and minute as well as the exit hour and minute with text boxes. Hours will be entered in a 24 hour format. Once the submit button is selected, the webpage should display the charge, total number of charges and running total of charges. Note that the latter two values will be maintained as the page is used repetedly.

Create and use functions calculateTime and calculateCharge, the former to figure the amount of time in the garage and the latter to figure the charge.

I got the HTML running, however I cannot get the values to display on to the textbox. I also cannot figure out how to calculate the charge. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Parking Charge</title>
</head>
<body><div align="center">
<form id="1"><h1><p style="background-color:black ; color:gold;">Parking Garage Charge Calculator</p></h1><hr>
<p>ENTRY TIME: <input type = "number" name = "EntryTime" id = "entTime"></p>
<p>EXIT TIME :  <input type="number" id="extTime" name="ExitTime">
<p>Number of Hours Parked: <input type ="number" name="noOfHours" id="nh"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="calculate" name="calc" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateTime()"/>
<input type="reset" id="resetBtn" value="Clear"><br><br>
<input type="number" id="total" name="totalCost" placeholder="Your Total Payment" readonly/><hr>
</form>
</div>
</body>
<script src="P2JS.js"></script>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function calculateTime(){

var EntryTime = document.getElementById('entTime').value;
var ExitTime = document.getElementById('extTime').value;

var noOfHours = (EntryTime - ExitTime);
document.getElementById("nh").innerHTML = noOfHours;
}

/*Function to calculate the payment on the number of hours parked*/

function calculateCharge(){
var charge = 3.50;
var payment = (noOfHours * charge);
if (noOfHours <= 3){
    totalPayment = charge * noOfHours;
    return payment;
}
else {
    payment = ((noOfHours - 3) * (charge + 0.50)) + (charge * 3);
    return payment;
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're asking us to write the code for you. Please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Well, any help would be appreciated. My main concern is that I am not able to display the hours entered by the user to display on to the textbox.

Comment: The second function is a mathematical mess tbh... The values and the equations don't match what you said you wanted them to be. And totalPayment isn't a variable, yet you try to assign it a value...

I would suggest rethinking what is the result you want and figure the equation needed before trying to make it into a function.

Comment: As of right now this function is:
If the person stay for less than 3 hours their payment will be the charge(3,50) times 1, 2 or 3 so between 3,50 and 10,50... this does't reflect ''$2.00 minimum fee to park for up to three hours.''

then if more than 3hours the payment is the no of hours more(that's fine) times the charge+0,50$... Euh so they will be charge again, 3,50 per hour + the 0,50 fee? + again the 3,50 charge times 3 hours ??
If a person park for 5 hours that would sum up to 18,50$....

Comment: @salix Thank you for the honest feedback, I will work on that. I am new to Javascript programming.

Comment: what is the status of this question? there was an answer given. If it solved it, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the hours aren't showing is because your are using an input to display it and asking it to show it in the innerHTML which input doesn't have.

So what you want is give it a value instead.
Just add ' value="" ' to your input html

```
<input type="number" name="noOfHours" value="" id="nh">
```

and change '.innerHTML' for '.value' in your js.

```
document.getElementById("nh").value = noOfHours;
```

You might also want to change your equation for ExitTime - EntryTime because right now it gives you a negative number of hours ;)